# Trying to create a top ten list in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to generate a top ten list of locations according to my MySQL database on the index page and haven't had any luck to speak of. I know I will need to use .find is some way, but I am not sure how I can call upon the location table within the index page to do this. When I try to call Locations.find I get

uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Locations

Anyone here have any clue how I should move forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd suggest [this](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) book, if you haven't already got it.

Second: If you generated your model the way you should do it, it should be called `Location` not `LocationS`. So you should try using `Location.find` or, if you just want all records, you could do `Location.all`

Comment: Thank you so much for noticing that error. It's now working the way I thought it should.